# Output Differ in Linux and Windows?

Tags: python, pandas, resampling

```
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_csv('mydataset.csv', parse_dates=['Timestamp'] )
    #print (df)

     mask=(df['Timestamp'].dt.minute<10) & (df['Timestamp'].dt.hour==0)

     df1 = df[mask]
     print (df1)

     df1= df1.set_index('Timestamp')
     #print df1

     df1= df1.resample('D').mean()
     print (df1)
```

this is my Code for finding Average.

Output for Windows:-

```
 Timestamp  Temperature1  Temperature2
2016-09-01         53.80      45.80  
2016-09-02         32.00      56.60  
2016-09-03         30.80      58.30  
2016-09-04         31.00      55.60  
2016-09-05         31.10      55.60  
2016-09-06         31.20      55.50  
2016-09-07         30.80      54.90  
2016-09-08         30.80      54.60  
2016-09-09         31.40      55.10  
2016-09-10         30.70      54.80  
2016-09-11         31.00      54.60  
2016-09-12         31.70      54.90  
2016-09-13         31.10      54.70  
2016-09-14           NaN        NaN   
2016-09-15           NaN        NaN  
2016-09-16         30.30      54.90  
2016-09-17           NaN        NaN  
2016-09-18         31.00      64.60  
2016-09-19           NaN        NaN  
2016-09-20         30.50      56.65  
2016-09-21         30.10      56.40  
2016-09-22         30.00      55.60  
2016-09-23         30.30      56.30  
2016-09-24         49.25      44.00  
2016-09-25         51.50      47.10   
2016-09-26         50.10      45.35  
2016-09-27         50.25      48.00  
2016-09-28         49.70      45.90  
2016-09-29         51.05      48.15  
2016-09-30         50.50      48.50
```

This is actual my desire output, but here also some of the dates are giving NaN value, not understanding why this is happening, because my data is proper and its giving NaN.

In linux machine the output is like

```
Temperature1       35.779053  
temperature2       53.593647
```

giving combined Avg not individually datewise.

I want datewise AVG.
please help me with this.
I am using :-
python: 2.7.12
pandas: 0.17.1

Comment: are there any 0's in the data? could be causing a div/0 resulting in NAN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [Pandas 0.17.1](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) you can do it this way:

```
df1.resample('D', how='mean')
```

PS [the Resample API has been changed in Pandas 0.18.0](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.0/whatsnew.html#resample-api)...

In regards to NaN's - you can check how many entries per day you have:

```
df1.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='1D')).size()
```

Comment: @Til.N, can you post an output of `print(df1.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='1D')).size())`? Especially for the days with NaN's...

Comment: out put is coming like that 
2016-09-14    1  
2016-09-15    1  
2016-09-17    1  
2016-09-19    1

Comment: @Til.N, most probably you have NaN's in your data for those days. Check this: `df1.loc[df1.isnull().any(1)]`. The question is what do you want to have instead of NaN's if `resample().mean()` will give you NaNs?

Comment: thanks..
In all this examples its giving us for all dates Avg ..if we want for specific date then what we will do?